# Not receiving the image from database PHP LongBlob

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i'm trying to receive my images from the database. I already can insert the images, but I don't know if it goes wrong overthere or that I do something wrong with getting the image.

The code for inserting the image:

```
    public function Save(){
        /*** check if a file was uploaded ***/
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) && getimagesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) != false)
            {
            /***  get the image info. ***/
            $size = getimagesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
            /*** assign our variables ***/
            $type = $size['mime'];
            $imgfp = fopen($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 'rb');
            $size = $size[3];
            $name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
            $maxsize = 99999999;


            /***  check the file is less than the maximum file size ***/
            if($_FILES['userfile']['size'] < $maxsize )
                {
                /*** connect to db ***/
                $db = new Db();

                /*** our sql query ***/
                $sql = "INSERT INTO Foto (image_type ,image, image_size, image_name) 
                    VALUES ('". $type ."',
                            '". $imgfp ."',
                            '". $size ."',
                            '". $name ."');";
                $db->conn->query($sql);

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM Foto ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;";
                $select = $db->conn->query($sql);

                $numberofRows = $select->num_rows;

                if($numberofRows == 1)
                {
                    while ($oneSelect = $select->fetch_assoc())
                    {   
                        return $oneSelect;
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new Exception("Fout");
                }


                }
            else
                {
                throw new Exception("Bestand is te groot");
                }
            }
        else
            {
            throw new Exception("Dit extensie is niet ondersteund");
            }
        }
```

The code for loading the images:

```
<?php 
include_once("classes/Db.class.php");
//$id = $_GET['id'];
$id = "33";
$db = new Db();
$sql = "SELECT image, image_type FROM Foto WHERE id = '". $id ."';";
$result = $db->conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
if(sizeof($row) == 2)
{
    header("Content-type: ".$row['image_type']);
    echo $row['image'];
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("Out of bounds Error");
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually inserting the image data. Read up on the [`fopen()`](http://php.net/fopen) function, it doesn't return the image data, but a file handle that can then be used for reading from or writing to a file (using, for example, [`fread()`](http://php.net/fread) or [`fwrite()`](http://php.net/fwrite)). Easy way out is using [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents).

But take my advice, it's really bad practice to store images in the database. They're files and better off stored on the file system (hence the name). Makes serving them a lot faster too, as no PHP request has to be executed. Store the filename and maybe a relative path to the file in the database instead.